# Solve $x+3<\sqrt{x+33}$ : Solution Verification

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

First of all the part inside the square root should be greater than or equal to $0$. So, 
$x+33 \ge0$
$\Rightarrow x \ge -33$

Now I solved the inequality,
$x+3<\sqrt{x+33}$
$\Rightarrow(x+3)^2<{x+33}$
$\Rightarrow x^2+9+6x<{x+33}$
$\Rightarrow x^2+5x-24 < 0$
$\Rightarrow (x+8)(x-3) < 0$
$\Rightarrow -8<x<3$

Now combining the two results i.e. $ x \ge -33$ and $ -8<x<3$ , the answer should be $ -8<x<3$ as per my understanding but this is not the correct answer that has been provided. What am I doing wrong? Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The issue is here: $x+3<\sqrt{x+33} \Rightarrow(x+3)^2<{x+33}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inequality $\sqrt A> B$ we need of course $A\ge 0$, and you did it correct, but before squaring both sides we need to consider two cases:

- when $B<0$ the inequality is always satisfied
- when $B\ge 0$ we can square both sides to find other solutions

and you went wrong in that second step.

Therefore in general we have:

> $$\sqrt A> B \iff \begin{cases}A\ge 0\\B<0 \end{cases}\quad \lor \quad \begin{cases}A\ge 0\\B>0\\A>B^2 \end{cases}$$

Comment: So I'll have to take these two cases and come up with the solutions for both the cases and then combine the solution, right?

Comment: @Ganit Yes the solution is the union of the solutions for the two systems.

Comment: thanks...i got the correct answer. thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Ganit Well done! The most important thing is that you undestand the reasoning process under that and why we need to consider the two cases. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

You can only square both sides iff both sides and the argument of the square root are nonnegative.

Under such conditions, the proposed inequation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
x + 3 < \sqrt{x + 33} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x+3)^{2} < x + 33\\\\
x+3 \geq 0\\\\
x + 33 \geq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + 6x + 9 < x + 33\\\\
x\geq -3
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + 6x - 34 < 0\\\\
x \geq -3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Moreover, notice whenever $-33 \leq x \leq -3$, the LHS is negative and the RHS is positive.

Hence the interval $[-33,-3]$ is also a solution.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The correct answer is $-33<x<3$.

Comment: Are you sure? Because $-33 + 3 = -30 < 0 = \sqrt{-33 + 33}$. Similarly, $-3 + 3 = 0 < \sqrt{-3 + 33} = \sqrt{30}$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B3%3Csqrt%28x%2B33%29

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you square. Notice that $x+3 \leq 0$ whenever $x \leq -3$. Also, $\sqrt{x+33} \geq 0$ for all values of $x \geq -33$. You should take this into consideration when evaluating the inequality.